# html not loading multiple images

Tags: html, image

I am trying to make an image page for a website and only one of the images loads. Anybody have advice?

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">

 <h1 style="color:white"> Images </h1>
 <div class="row">
 
    <div class="column">
 <img src="C:\Users\Scott Jackson\Downloads\boat.jpg" alt="C:\Users\Scott Jackson\Downloads\boat.jpg" class="image1" height="250">
 </div>
 
 <div class="column">
 <img src="‪‪‪C:\Users\Scott Jackson\Downloads\boat.jpg" alt="C:\Users\Scott Jackson\Downloads\boat.jpg" class="image2" height="250">
 </div>
 </div>```
 
 


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYky7.png
````

Comment: That doesn't even seem possible since both image sources are the same. Have you done any debugging? Any error messages in the console? Try clearing your cache?

Comment: the different is your class name, try check that

Answer (score 0):

move your images to the same directory as your HTML files and change your img tag's src to a relative path, i.e. something like `<img src="‪‪‪boat.jpg">`

Comment: I've done what you asked and it did not fix the issue. the other image just isn't loading for some reason. I'm baffled